# Web based video capturing system

Tags: html, browser, video-capture

I have to write the system that performs the following:

1. User loads page from server
2. Page contains "start recording" button
3. User clicks this button
4. In case user has web camera, a video capturing screen appears
5. This screen has 3 controls "start", "finish", "send"
6. User performs capturing (recording) and sends captured info to a server

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to implement capturing (including viewing of captured
   info) as part of the page functionality?
2. Which technologies to use (flash/HTML5/JS, etc)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. HTML and Javascript do not have access to web cams. Flash is the technology to use (though you need to cater for those without webcams and remember that people need to allow your page/application access to the web cam).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAVA [applets](http://java.sun.com/applets/) to do the job.
you write in java. when the user open the url it open the applet.
Also you can use java webstart [java web start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html)

you may make use of some opensource projects like:

http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/